# How to add a NumericUpDown In JqxGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

Does anyone can help me in how can I add a NumericUpDonw field in JqxGrid ?

Here's my column:

```
columns: [
        { text: 'Ano', datafield: 'Ano', width: '4%', filter: fdata, cellsalign: 'center', columntype: 'number' },            
        ]
```

So I want that the header of the column be display a field with NumericUpDown buttons.

I read on JqWidgets but didn't find anything that fits my needs.
(http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-cellsformatting.htm)

Thanks

Comment: Editor and jqxNumberInput help you. You may check this  link. http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/spinbuttonsstep-of-jqxnumberinput-in-grid-editor-not-working/